# main.swf (built on as3) reload child.swf (built on as2)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have a problem with reload child.swf. On first load (loadPattern()) it works fine, but afrer unload and load second time it works uncorrectly(don't load photo content) without any errors.

Child.swf built on as2.

main.swf built on as3.

```
var childSwf:Object;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var childLoaded:Boolean = false;

function loadPatternHandler(event:Event):void 
{ 
   childSwf = event.target.content; 
   childSwf.x = 0;
   childSwf.y = -35;

} 

function loadPattern():void
{
    stopPattern();

    var myswf:String = "child.swf";

    var Xpos:Number = 0;
    var Ypos:Number = 0;

    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myswf);

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadPatternHandler); 

    //loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

    loader.load(req);
    loader.x=Xpos;
    loader.y=Ypos;
    addChild(loader);
    childLoaded=true;

}

function stopPattern():void
{
    if(childLoaded)
    {
        loader.unloadAndStop();
        //loader.unload();
        removeChild(loader);
        loader=null;
        loader = new Loader();
        childLoaded = false;
    }
}

loadPattern();
```

Is it not fully unloaded on stopPattern()?

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be putting all the logic to add the child.swf in the handler once loaded - loadPatternHandler function. You are calling stopPattern immediately in loadPattern which will remove it again.

Comment: stopPattern remove previous child1.swf before load next child2.swf, or for reload I call only loadPattern(). Maybe after reload, child.swf change work dir and can't load a config.xml file. I don't know how to trace this.

Comment: It's been a while since I used a `loader`, so this may be somewhat off-base.  Do you need `addChild(loader)`?  I think that the object is loaded in the handler (`event.target.content` is a reference to something like `loader.content`), so this is unnecessary.  Also, you never remove the reference held in `childSwf`, so there will be at least one reference left.  `childSwf = null` may help.  Further, I don't think you are actually putting the content in the display list . . . maybe try `addChild(childSwf)` and `removeChild(childSwf)`.

Comment: I tried childSwf = null in stopPattern(), nothing changes.
addChild(childSwf) for child1.swf(built on as3) works fine, but for child.swf(built on as2) it gives error: 
Error #2180: It is illegal to move AVM1 content (AS1 or AS2) to a different part of the displayList when it has been loaded into AVM2 (AS3) content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into generic AS2 loading solutions?  I have used SWFBridge with excellent results:

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html